# How does the Global Image ID work ? - Linking Dual-EELS datasets

Tags: dm-script

Is there a way to script a pair of dual-EELS SIs so that DM recognises them as siblings (say, for use in the "SI->Align SI by Peak" menu option)?

I have a script which performs a transformation on a pair of dualEELS SIs where the results are given in new images with all the tags copied from the original. The new SIs do not seem to be acknowledged by the SI options as a pair, however. A MWE of how this occurs is below:

```
image a, b

GetTwoLabeledImagesWithPrompt("Get SI", \
    "Get DualEELS SIs", \
    "Low-Loss", a, \
    "High-Loss", b)

image LL, HL

LL := a.ImageClone()
HL := b.ImageClone()

LL.ShowImage()
HL.ShowImage()
```

Assuming that the two inputs are real dualEELS SIs.  Attempting afterward to run a method like "SI->Align SI by Peak" on the outputs does not recognise the second SI as a sibling.

I suspect that my issue is in properly assigning the four `EELS:Dual acquire sibling:UID` tags highlighted in the image provided, however I have no idea how (or if) these are accessible from the scripting language.

[image: dualEELS SI tags]

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to render.

Comment: I know you're after a script solution - see my answer below - but it should be added that most (all?) DM-Methods which look-up a sibling tend to prompt users with a selection-dialog. Once selected, the chosen images are often (always?) tagged so that they are subsequently recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, "siblings" in DigitalMicrograph are recognized by tag-checks and tagging of the *Unique Image Id* (**UID**).

Depending on the exact application/plugin, there might be additional tag-checks before a sibling can be accepted (i.e. "is it EELS data?", "is it spatially compatible?", etc.) but he prime-mechanism is using the **UID**.

#### A bit of background info

The UID is a set of four long-numbers generated at random whenever a new image data is created, and then subsequently stored with the data. It is "unique" by the assumption that a set of four randomly generated 8-byte longs are "unique".

If you create an image, save it to disc, and open it, the UID will be the same. (It is stored with the data.)

If you `ImageClone()` an image, it gets a new UID.

If you copy a image file on the hard drive and rename it, it will retain the UID.

#### Creating and using UIDs

The commands to get an image's UID are described in the F1 help documentation here:

[image: Help]

And the example section even has a script showing how one uses UID to "link" data together:
[image]

Comment: The example in the F1 stored the 4 longs in a single tag (as long-RECT). For the purpose of the DEELS you will need to replicated the exact tag-structure, i.e. the taggroup labelled "UID" with 4 sub-tags as in your screenshot.

Comment: Cheers!  I've added in some code based on the info in the help file and everything works as expected now.